# Parameter implicit "arg" in functions not work in Lua

Tags: lua

I have a problem in use implicit parameter `arg` in functions.

The code not works. The documentation, http://www.lua.org/pil/5.2.html, should works.

```
function listar_um (...)
  for i,v in ipairs(arg) do
    print("usando args " .. arg[i])  
  end
end
listar_um("Olá", 1, "Dois")
```

This code works with the declaring variable `lista`.

```
function listar_um (...)
  lista = {...}

  for i,v in ipairs(lista) do
    print("não usando args " .. lista[i])  
  end
end
listar_um("Olá", 1, "Dois")
```

Why the first example does not work?

Script for test: http://www.codeshare.io/IPwRJ
Execute on-line script: http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lua_online.php

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The first edition of PiL](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) talks about Lua 5.0. The use of `arg` is available in Lua 5.0, while it's removed since Lua 5.1

You can find it in [Lua 5.0 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.0/manual.html#2.5.7), but not in [Lua 5.1 reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#2.5.9).

The edition [the online interpreter](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_lua_online.php) uses is Lua 5.2, you can find out by `print(_VERSION)`.

---

**Edit**: after some tests, it seems that `arg` is still available in Lua 5.1, but not working in Lua 5.2.

Comment: `arg` still exists in the main Lua 5.1 implementation for backwards compatibility. It's definitely not in LuaJIT though, and possibly not in other implementations.